# Dojo Dialog with confirmation button

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to add a generic dialog with "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons support callback functions.

How can I achieve this with a Dojo AMD?

For example:

```
  myDialog = new Dialog ({

  title: "My Dialog",
  content: "Are you sure, you want to delete the selected Record?",
  style: "width: 300px",
  onExecute:function(){ //Callback function 
      console.log("Record Deleted") 
  },
  onCancel:function(){ 
      console.log("Event Cancelled") } 
  });
  // create a button to clear the cart
   new Button({ label:"Ok"
       onClick: myDialog.onExecute()
   }

   new Button({ label:"Cancel"
        onClick: function(){ myDialog.onCancel() }
   }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up when I had been facing the same question. It's not completely programmatic, but using the template makes the code more readable and flexible for changes.

Better to see once than to hear 100 times, so see all the code below live at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/wkydY/

The main principle I employ is the fact that `dijit.Dialog::content` may not only be a string, but also a widget instance. So I subclass `dijit.Dialog` to declare `ConfirmDialog` class. In `ConfirmDialog::constuctor()` I declare and instantize a widget from a template and set it to be dialog's content. Then I wire `onClick` actions in `ConfirmDialog::postCreate()` method:

```
var ConfirmDialog = declare(Dialog, {

    title: "Confirm",
    message: "Are you sure?",

    constructor: function(/*Object*/ kwArgs) {
        lang.mixin(this, kwArgs);

        var message = this.message;

        var contentWidget = new (declare([_Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
            templateString: template, //get template via dojo loader or so
            message: message    
        }));
        contentWidget.startup();
        this.content = contentWidget;
    },

    postCreate: function() {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        this.connect(this.content.cancelButton, "onClick", "onCancel");
    }

})
```

The template markup:

```
<div style="width:300px;">

  <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="contentNode">
        ${message}              
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">

    <button
      data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"
      data-dojo-attach-point="submitButton"
      type="submit"
    >
      OK
    </button>

    <button
      data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"
      data-dojo-attach-point="cancelButton"
    >
      Cancel
    </button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Now use `ConfirmDialog` instead of `dijit.Dialog`:

```
var confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog({ message: "Your message..."});
confirmDialog.show();
```

**Important:** Do not forget to disconnect any connects to the dialogs callbacks and destroy dialog when closed.

If you use `ConfirmDialog` often and in multiple places of your code consider this:

```
var MessageBox = {};
MessageBox.confirm = function(kwArgs) {
    var confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog(kwArgs);
    confirmDialog.startup();

    var deferred = new Deferred();
    var signal, signals = [];

    var destroyDialog = function() {
        array.forEach(signals, function(signal) {
            signal.remove();
        });
        delete signals;
        confirmDialog.destroyRecursive();
    }

    signal = aspect.after(confirmDialog, "onExecute", function() {
        destroyDialog();
        deferred.resolve('MessageBox.OK');
    });
    signals.push(signal);

    signal = aspect.after(confirmDialog, "onCancel", function() {
        destroyDialog();   
        deferred.reject('MessageBox.Cancel');            
    });
    signals.push(signal);

    confirmDialog.show();
    return deferred;
}
```

Your code will be more readable and you will not have to deal with cleaning up:

```
MessageBox.confirm().then(function() {
    console.log("MessageBox.OK")
});
```

Comment: First dojo widget with inner widget working example I find working! Thanks a lot :). I find the official doc so poor on this topic.

Comment: Official doc is poor in most cases ;)

Answer (score 13):

Here's how to use `dijit/ConfirmDialog` and configure its buttons.

```
require(["dijit/ConfirmDialog"], function(ConfirmDialog){

    // create instance
    var dialog = new ConfirmDialog({
        title: "Session Expiration",
        content: "the test. Your session is about to expire. Do you want to continue?",
        style: "width: 300px"
    });

    // change button labels
    dialog.set("buttonOk","Yes");
    dialog.set("buttonCancel","No");

    // register events
    dialog.on('execute', function() { /*do something*/ });
    dialog.on('cancel', function() { /*do something*/ });

    // show
    dialog.show();
});
```

Comment: You can also add a `onExecute` property to the option object in the constructor, that holds the event handling function, instead of registering the events afterwards.

Comment: this should be the number one answer.

Answer (score 7):

Dojo 1.10 includes a new [dijit/ConfirmTooltipDialog](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/ConfirmDialog.html) with built-in OK and Cancel buttons.

Comment: If you need blocking behavior, have a look at my https://github.com/speich/DialogConfirm

Answer (score 2):

**Dojo Confirm Dialog** is very simple and helpful. 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/ConfirmDialog.html

```
require(["dijit/ConfirmDialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ConfirmDialog){
    myDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
        title: "My ConfirmDialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        buttonCancel: "Label of cancel button",
        buttonOk: "Label of OK button",
        style: "width: 300px",
        onCancel: function(){
            //Called when user has pressed the Dialog's cancel button, to notify container.
        },
        onExecute: function(){
           //Called when user has pressed the dialog's OK button, to notify container.
        }
    });
});
```