# Instantiating dijit.Dialog from a template I can't get it to initialize properly

Tags: dojo

In Dojo, I am trying to extend dijit.Dialog using templates.  When I instantiate it, I get only the text in the dialog box, without the borders or close button.  Is there some additional step I need to do to get it fully initialized?

My template is in template.html, it looks like so:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="dynFilter" jsId="dynFilter">
"Dynamic Dialog"
</div>
```

Here is the dojo.declare:

```
dojo.declare(
    "template.dialog",                                  // class name
    [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated, dijit.Dialog],    // parent classes
    {
    templateString : dojo.cache("autonomics", "template.html"),
    }
);
```

After I instantiate it, I call .startup(), which doesn't seem to do anything, then .show(), which does place it on the page, missing most of its functionality.

```
var dialog = new template.dialog();
dialog.startup();
dialog.show();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the template of the original `dijit/Dialog` when subclassing.

Have a look to my answer to [Dojo Dialog with confirmation button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401512/dojo-dialog-with-confirmation-button/10405938#10405938) which solves the issue you are experiencing. Or go directly to working example at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/wkydY/