# dojo 1.4 blocking yes/no dialog replacement for window.confirm

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog, blocking

I am stuck in dojo 1.4. 
Need a synchronous (blocking) dialog replacement for window.confirm().
why : I would like the buttons to be YES/NO instead of OK/CANCEL.
This dialog will be called from multiple parts of the app -- so needs proper cleanup. Is there a dojo library that has this functionality ? 
I would prefer all dynamic code so I can include this new dialog from within a .js file or a html/jsp file but something working is appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve it in a synchronous manner. Not in JavaScript. Anyway you can elegantly employ Promise API and solve it asynchronously as I described in [Dojo Dialog with confirmation button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401512/dojo-dialog-with-confirmation-button/10405938#10405938).

Comment: I want the confirm YES/NO dialog to be displayed on form submit. If this is not synchronous, then the form gets submitted much before the user answers YES/NO -- so doesn't work.

Comment: @anjanb, you can [prevent the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) (form submit), and then submit it via JavaScript when you're ready.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it synchronous, but you can prevent the form from submitting by `event.preventDefault()` or `onsubmit="return false;"` as @FakeRainBrigand mentioned.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/73PuE/.

[image]

It employs [the confirm dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401512/dojo-dialog-with-confirmation-button/10405938#10405938) I mentioned in the comment above. It is written in Dojo 1.8, but it should be more or less the same as in 1.4, just use `dojo.connet` instead of `dojo/on`:

```
var form1 = dom.byId("form1");

on(form1, "submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = event.target;
    MessageBox.confirm({ message: "Submit form?" }).then(function() {
        // submit the form upon a click on `Yes`
        form.submit();
    });        
});
```

You can achieve the same **in plain vanilla JavaScript**:

```
function confirmHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = event.target;
    // ask for a confirmation and if confirmed invoke:
    // form.submit();
}
```

Register handler on the form:

```
<form onsubmit="confirmHandler(event);">
```