# Dojo widgets and decorator pattern?

Tags: widget, dojo

anyone can help me on applying the decorator pattern on Dijit widgets?

For example, given a `FormA_Widget` which shows a form with some input texts and buttons.
The idea is to create a `FormB_Widget`, which "extends" the `FormA_Widget` decorating it with some more radio buttons, inputs, etc.

I know how to create a templated custom widget and also how to "extend" a widget, what I need is to know how to "inject" the template of `FormB_Widget` at some place within the `FormA_widget` to add the desired "decoration2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example I created: http://plnkr.co/edit/dGMJ8UBQ9dT3dGQPQSeu?p=preview

This is the simplest possible solution, but it requires a couple of tiny changes in `FormA`:

**FormA.js**:

```
var FormA = declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {   
    templateString: template,

    templateExtensionString: "" // <= add `templateExtensionString` property
});
```

**FormA.html** - add `templateExtensionString` placeholder into widget template:

```
<div>
    <div><!-- FormA markup --></div>

    <div>${!templateExtensionString}</div>

    <div><!-- FormA markup --></div>
</div>
```

**N.B.:** To prevent `_TemplatedMixin` from escaping quotations within a string, place a "!" before the full variable name.

Now you can extend `FormA`:

```
var FormB = declare([FormA], {

    templateExtensionString: template // FormB template (dojo/text!./FormB.html)

});
```

In the case you cannot modify `FormA` have a look at my answer to [Dojo Dialog with confirmation button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401512/dojo-dialog-with-confirmation-button/10405938#10405938) and consider employing similar strategy here.