# Dojo Dialog with confirmation button with a widget as content

Tags: dojo, confirm

Im trying to implement generic dojo confirmation dialog. I found great resource in stackoverflow on how to do it in link: [Dojo Dialog with confirmation button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401512/dojo-dialog-with-confirmation-button?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The sample which is mentioned in the above link works absolutely fine as in http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/wkydY/ .

Now that i wanted to extend this to support more complicated widget containing dojo data type and dojo attach points inside this dialog. I try to achieve this by setting the message of the dialog.
i.e.

```
message: "<div data-dojo-attach-point='myAttachPoint'><button data-dojo-type='dijit/form/Button' type='button'>Click me</button></div>";
```

(see this code at here : http://jsfiddle.net/wkydY/304/)

When I do that and clicking on MessageBox.Confirm' button doesnt bring up the dialog box as it would in the original version. What exactly am i doing wrong or missing a step in here?

(edited : based on comment)

Comment: "the code isn't working anymore" - please be more specific here

Comment: The code that i modified can be found at :http://jsfiddle.net/wkydY/304/ . In this version of code since im setting the widget content, clicking on 'MessageBox.Confirm' button doesnt bring up the confirmation dialog as it would in the original version.

Comment: Please update your question so *its text* contains the specification of what you mean by "the code isn't working". This is so crucial piece of information that it shouldn't be just in a comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here

```
var confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
    title: "My Title",
    message: "<div data-dojo-attach-point='myAttachPoint'><button data-dojo-type='dijit/form/Button' type='button'>Click me</button></div>";       
});
```

as there should not be a semicolon in an object definition, i.e. after `message: '...';`

Also, as you are using non-AMD Dojo, you should put `type="dijit.form.Button"` into the message.

So the correct version of the lines above is:

```
var confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
    title: "My Title",
    message: "<div data-dojo-attach-point='myAttachPoint'><button data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button' type='button'>Click me</button></div>"       
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/wkydY/305/